# Python 3 craps simulation

Tags: python

I'm not sure how I could incorporate my roll() function into the playRound().  The playRound is supposed to simulate the actual round of craps.  I have to have the roll() function as is along with all of the other code. The only segment I can edit is the playRound() function.

```
from random import (random, randint)

def roll():
    return randint( 1, 6 ), randint( 1, 6 )

def playRound():


def main():
    print("Craps simulation") 
    while True:
        response = input("Enter an integer value > 0 ")
        if response == "": 
          print("Thank you for your business!")
          break

        try:
          num_trials = int(response)
          if num_trials < 1: 
              raise ValueError("Input must be >= 1 ")

          roundsPlayed = 0
          wins = 0
          while roundsPlayed < num_trials:
              roundsPlayed += 1
              if playRound(): 
                  wins += 1

            print( "Probability of winning is {0:>0.2%}".format( wins/num_trials  ) )

        except ValueError as err:
          print( err )
        except TypeError as err:
          print( err )

main()
```

Comment: did you try `d1,d2 =roll()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowed to call any function as long as it is in scope. In Python, every function defined on the outermost scope layer is callable from anywhere within the script (or module namespace, if you're using it as such). This is referred to as the global scope.

When you have a function that returns multiple values, Python lets you catch them very easily with different variables by using commas to separate them.

Here's a small example of calling `roll` within `playRound` and storing the return values in two variables:

```
def playRound():
    roll1, roll2 = roll()
```

Comment: Wow thank you both. You guys saved my life for sure.  Very simple fix I'm a little embarrassed I missed that.